# GCOV Profiling: ".gcda:Version mismatch"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcov, lcov

I'm currently compiling sources using --coverage, with GCC. The generated .gcno files (and the instrumented libraries) are to be packed in a RPM and the code coverage evaluated on another, target platform.

Now, I'm having a problem getting the coverage data, because when I run the programs calling the instrumented code, I get messages telling me that I have a version mismatch. They look like:

".gcda:Version mismatch - expected A85R got B12R"

Now, I've seen this question: [GCOV Version mismatch - expected 700e got 408R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343696/gcov-version-mismatch-expected-700e-got-408r) which says I must use the same toolchain when compiling and when executing the code.

I'm compiling using **gcc 11.2.1**, and **gcov --version** says the same thing, on the source platform.
On the target platform, *gcc --version* and *gcov --version* both give that very same version number.

The compiling and the testing is done on the same "physical" machine, but on different Docker containers. On both of them, the GCC version and gcov version are the same

I've done further testing: even on the Docker container where we compile, we cannot run the coverage, and get the same error. Or, to be more precise, when compiled using gcc 11, it will say "version mismatch". However, when compiled using gcc 8.5, it works.

The setup is that we have the GCC 11 toolset, which **requires** gcc 8.5 to install. By default, gcc 8.5 is enabled, and you have to use a script (provided by the gcc 11 toolset) to enable the later. That script updates different variables, like the PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, etc., to look at GCC 11 first.

However, I'm pretty sure it doesn't upgrade the **libc.so** library, and that it's the cause of the problem: I compiled two of our simplest libs (each of them having no dependencies whatsoever, except libc) with gcc 11, in coverage mode. Then I compiled a simple test program, without coverage, calling some functions from the two instrumented libs. I checked (with **elfread -d**), the program only links to these two libs (and libc).

Calling this test program while on the compilation container results in the **Version mismatch** error, which would lead me to conclude that our libc.so isn't compatible with gcc 11.

I wonder if there is a way to get a "native" gcc 11, instead of a "toolkit" package which has to be installed over a gcc 8.5 (my colleague in charge of creating the Docker containers tells me that for gcc 9 and above, there are only "toolkit" packages, requiring gcc 8.5 to install).

Our target architecture runs on Rocky Linux, and I *think* our development architecture is a Redhat, if it has any importance here.

Comment: Do you compile and link everything on the same machine? Does the code use any libraries compiled with a different compiler version? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I updated the question, with more information, and recent findings.

Comment: You seem to have found the cause of the problem. Apparently you have parts of your program compiled with different GCC versions. Now you have to find out how to fix this. Can you add background information or links for your (or your colleague's) statement "GCC 11 toolset [...] which requires gcc 8.5 to install"? How exactly do you install GCC 11? Maybe you have to install libc separately?

Comment: I don't know exactly how those are installed. I know that to enable gcc 11, there is a script /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/enable, and it changes PATH, MANPATH, PCP_DIR, and INFOPATH, along with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH

I'm not sure if we can get a distribution where the libC is built using a recent GCC, however (I don't necessarily need gcc 11, but I need a version which understands the **-fprofile-prefix-path** option, which gcc 8.5 doesn't)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information instead of using comments for this purpose. Maybe you should write this underlying problem as a separate question. I don't know if `-fprofile-prefix-path` can be replaced with using environment variables `GCOV_PREFIX` and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP` at runtime.